# Is it possible for a .NET Remoting Service to communicate with WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-remoting

We have existing services written with .NET Remoting and WCF technologies in different sites. Is there a mechanism for the two services to communicate with each other? If it's possible, how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

WCF service can be easily consumed by remoting client as in this case the Remoting Service becomes client of WCF service. The other way around i am not as the protocol that remoting works on is dependent on windows stack + the port the remoting service runs on.